# Duplicar una lista y agregarla a otra lista en Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa donde me solicitan duplicar los elementos de una lista que en este caso se llama PersonalItems a otra lista llamada CommonItems, pero no sé como hacer dicha función, lo llevo así:

```js
public class Main{
    private static boolean searchID;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Item>  PersonalItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
        ArrayList<Item>  CommonItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
        String arma = null;

        int op = 0;

        do{

            op = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, menuPrincipal()));

            switch(op){
                case 1:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "---Items que puedes elegir---\n---'Potion', 'Elixir', 'Ammo' y 'Weapon'--- " );
                    arma = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Escriba el nombre de su Item: ");
                    int weight = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Coloque el peso de su Item: "));
                    String description = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Coloque la descripcion de su Item: ");
                    PersonalItems.add(new Item(arma, weight ,description));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "---Item a buscar---");
                      int id= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Coloque el id: "));
                    PersonalItems.forEach(obj ->  {
                        if(obj.getID() == searchID) CommonItems.add(obj); });
                    break;
```

Comment: el case dos que es el que necesito no funciona, no se si alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo:(

Comment: Hola, y si simplemente igualas los arrays, y asi apuntaran al mismo objeto de la memoria heap

Comment: Sabes como usar el método "clone"? he visto que en muchos foros lo ocupan, pero sinceramente no he entendido muy bien el proceso

Comment: Siendote sincero nunca lo he usado.

Answer (score 0):

hay varias alternativas que puedes seguir para copiar una coleccion de datos en Java. Aqui hay tres opciones que puedes tomar, para incorporarlo en el codigo que ya llevas:

1. Usar el metodo addAll de la clase Collection para agregar todos los elementos de una lista.

   public class SomeClass{

   ```
    public static void main(String []args){
       ArrayList<Object> original = new ArrayList<Object>();
       // agregas elementos....
       ArrayList<Object> copia = new ArrayList<Object>();
       copia.addAll(original);
       // de esta manera se copian todos los elementos de una lista a la otra
    }
   }
   ```
2. Otra opcion es usar el metodo constructor que recibe otra lista. De esta manera:

   ```
   public class SomeClass{

        public static void main(String []args){
           ArrayList<Object> original = new ArrayList<Object>();
           // agregas elementos....
           ArrayList<Object> copia = new ArrayList<Object>(original);

        }
    }
   ```
3. Usando el metodo clone de la clase Collections:

   ```
    public class SomeClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<Object> lista = new ArrayList<Object>();       
            // agregas elementos.....      
            ArrayList<Object> clonada =  (ArrayList<Object>) lista.clone();
        }
    }
   ```

Puedes usar alguna de estas funciones y ponerlo como una opcion del menu con el switch que creaste, de esa manera puedes utilizar PersonalItems y CommonItems para duplicarse, usando Item como la clase Elemento de la coleccion que usaras para almacenarlo. Espero haber ayudado.